# process child nodejs объединение процессов в один поток для получения результата

Tags: node.js

Как можно объединить копии процессов воедино, для синхронной работы? Если использовать метод fork тогда создаются копии процессов, но как затем объединить результат воедино не где нет информации как это сделать. Не могу понять как это сделать , есть наводка на pm2, rabitmq, но что с этим делать не понятно.

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Опишите задачу которую вы пытаетесь решить

Comment: Процессы отдельные и "асинхронные", объединить их ниже по коду не выйдет. Объединять нужно результат, а не процессы. Дождитесь результат от обоих процессов и используйте их потом в одном процессе, а если нужно потом снова запустите два процесса. Выполнить задачу чисто как в C# например не получится.

Comment: Понял, тогда лучше go буду изучать